# Stretchingt geometry (shapes) up to desired point in any direction using FME?

Tags: editing, fme-form

How to stretch geometry -line, up to desired point in any direction in FME?

[image]

Comment: you had a qgis tag was that intentional?

Comment: You can use '2DDirectionExtender' transformer if that is available with you. it will ask you for length of line to be extended and at what angle .

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you start talking about "stretching" features in FME, two transformers comes to mind - the [**AffineWarper**](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/rubbersheeter.htm) and the [**RubberSheeter**](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/rubbersheeter.htm).

### Affine Warper

> Performs warping operations on the spatial coordinates of features. It
>   is used to adjust a set of observed features so they more closely
>   match some set of reference features. This transformer computes an
>   affine (scale, rotation, and offset) transformation based on Control
>   vector features and applies this transformation to the Observed
>   features to generate output, and produces good corrections when the
>   entire set of Observed data requires a single transformation.

### RubberSheeter

> Performs warping operations on the spatial coordinates of features. It is used to adjust a set of observed features so they more closely match some set of reference features. This transformer applies a different transformation to each Observed vertex, depending on its distance to nearby Control vectors. It produces good corrections when the distortions in the Observed data are not constant.